# Want to Add all amounts for each country

Tags: python, django, sum, addition

Hello I have a django app dealing with Sales/purchases. What I want to do is add amounts depending on thier country type.

Looking at the sales table, there are two different country types. Uk and EU (I know EU is not a country but nevermind :) )

**models.py**

```
COUNTRY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'UK'),
        (2, 'EU'),
        )
class Sale(models.Model):
    country_type = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Location", choices = COUNTRY_TYPE_CHOICES)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    description =  models.TextField(max_length = 400)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.amount)
```

Now I want to display the `amount` of all sales. I want two results. The sum of all `amount` from the UK, and the sum of `amount` that are from the EU. I'm slight confused how you would add all amounts because of the two different choice types.

Here is also my views file which may help as well.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    sales = Sale.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'sales':sales}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Update:** I have done so far

```
uk_sales = Sale.objects.filter(country_type='1')

{{uk_sales}}
```

On screen Gives me:  `<Sale: 467.99>, <Sale: 699.99>, <Sale: 499.99>]`

Now It wold be good If I could add all these values. Not counting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work quiet well for me.

```
uk_sales = Sale.objects.filter(country_type='1')
uk_amount = uk_sales.aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))['price']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Sale.objects.values('country_type').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: `@daniel:` Is there a way to only print the number only? Currently your method will print on the screen: `[{'country_type': 1L, 'amount__sum': Decimal('1499.97')}, {'country_type': 2L, 'amount__sum': Decimal('1000.00')}]`. I only want '1499.97' and  '1000.00' for example.

Comment: Come on, you've been asking questions on this site for ten months, you surely know enough Python by now to iterate through a list and choose values from a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Django 1.1 or newer, the you can use Django Aggregate Support with something like:

```
query_amount = Item.objects.extra(select={'sum': 'sum(amount)'}).values('sum', 'amount')
query_amount.query.group_by = ['country_type']
```

[Here's Django official documentation on the topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/). [And here's a nice tutorial](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-aggregation-tutorial/).

Comment: This answer doesn't use the aggregation functions.